# How to render methodAction of another Controller inside an action

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-flow, typo3-extensions

I'm using extbase, fluid system on typo3 to build a backend module.
I Have a Controller "MainController" action called 'AddBoxes' and I have another Controller called BoxElementsController, and there is an action method called 'popupBoxAction'.

I want to render the output of the BoxElementsController->popupBoxAction in the MainController-AddBoxesAction();

so that I can assign the output to my view variable.

How can i achieve this in Typo3 6.1.

Thanks

Comment: Would be helpful to see some code to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. There are several ways to reuse part of views or to do equal things in several templates. Partials or ViewHelper are maybe what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to instantiate you controller in you action then call `ControllerObject->initializeAction()` before calling your desired action.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can fetch data or output whatever you like from BoxElementsRepository

```
class MainController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

   protected $boxElementsRepository;

   public function injectBoxElementsRepository(BoxElementsRepository $boxElementsRepository) {
        $this->boxElementsRepository = $boxElementsRepository;
   }

   public function AddBoxesAction(){
        $popupBoxActionOutput = $this->boxElementsRepository->popupBox();
        $addBoxesAction = $this->mainRepository->findAll();


        $this->view->assignMultiple(array(
            'popupBoxActionOutput' => $popupBoxActionOutput,
            'addBoxesAction' => $addBoxesAction,
    ));
   }
}
```